# Creating a covariance data frame from a list containing columns with different lengths

Tags: r, list, covariance

I have a list of residuals from several regressions. The list contains 277 columns and 370 rows. The columns are of different lengths -> some of them begin with several rows of NA's. I would like to turn this residuals list into a covariance matrix for a GRS test. so far I have tried the melt function as well as trying to save the list to an excel file, however Ii can get neither to work (I am new to R and statistics). Is there a function in R that does this?

For example, the list consists residuals placed in vectors like this:

```
[[1]]
[1]  2 5 3 12 34 12 34

[[2]]
[1] na na na 3 4 34 6

[[3]]
[1] na na na na 8 1 12

[[4]]
[1] na na na 16 27 18 3

[[5]]
[1] na na na na 1 22 3
```

I would like to create a data frame like this

```
   1  2  3  4  5
1) 2  na na na na
2) 5  na na na na
3) 3  na na na na
4) 12 3  na 16 na
5) 34 4  8  27 1
6) 12 34 1  18 22
7) 34 6  12 3  3
```

From this data frame I would like to use the cov() function to get a covariance matrix of the residuals for a GRS test. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack. You'd probably get an answer (quicker) if you include the following three things: [1] some sample data (doesn't have to be real data if that's not possible), [2] the expected result from that data, [3] the code you tried and why that doesn't satisfy your requirements. (Or read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: `do.call(cbind, yourlist)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!